# Linear Algebar- Linear Transformation Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U, V, W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$. Let $T\colon V \to W$ be a linear transformation. Suppose that $T$ is onto. Show that there is a linear transformation $L \colon W \to V$ such that $TL=1_W$.

Comment: $T$ onto means $T$ is surjective? isn't that given by $T$ is a linear transformation?

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you first show what you have tried yourself.

Comment: Yes, surjective is the same as onto. 
What I know so far is that..
T:V->W is an ispmorphism if there exists an L:W->V such that LT=1v and TL:1w. where L is linear. It is only unique if it is onto and 1-1 (bijective). 

Im just not exactly sure how to show that there is in fact a linear transformation such that TL=1w.

Comment: What is $U$ and what is it's role in the question?

Comment: Sorry U doesnt play a role in this question..my bad.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**
(1) Given $W$ is finite dimensional, one can choose a finite basis $B_W=(w_1,...,w_k)$.
(2) $T$ is surjective, then ....
(2) *Any* linear transformation $L:W\to V$ is uniquely defined by $L(w_1),...,L(w_k)$. What do you want $L(w_i)$ to be?

Comment: If we choose a B_w=(w_1,...,w_k) for basis for W defining w_0=0. Then for v_1,...,v_2 in V, there exists a linear transformation L:W->V such that L(w_i)=v_i for i=1,2,...,n. I dont know where to go from here?

Comment: Then what can you say about $TL$?

Comment: TL(w) = T(L(w)) for all w in W.

Comment: TL(w1+w2)=T(L(w1+w2)=T(L(w1)+L(w2))

Comment: and TL(cw)=T(L(cw))=T(cL(w))=cT(L(w))=cTL(w)

Comment: What is $TL(w_i)$?

Comment: TL(w_i)=1_w(w_i)?

Comment: So $TL=1_W$ on the basis $B_W$. Then what follows?

Comment: Well since T is surjective for every w in W, there exists one v in V such that w=T(v)

ah...i really dont know now.

Comment: When two linear transformations are equal on a basis, then what?

Comment: They are unique

Comment: How can two things be unique?